# How to set the footer bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to set the footer at the bottom of the page according to screen size. See this screenshot. There is some gap bottom of the footer because on this page content is less. It is perfect in windows but I can see a problem with my mac. I have tried this way:
[image]
position: absolute; bottom: 0px is set at the bottom of the screen, not the page.

Comment: Will this help? https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Please provide your html and css

Comment: Thanks a lot! 3 number trick is working for me

Answer (score -1):

```css
    p {
        height: 60vh;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Hellow World</p>

</body>
<footer>I am a footer</footer>
```